# 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v15.0 and I'm trying to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` or `STUFF()` functions to get the concatenated result. But I am unable to draft a correct query.

I am getting the errors mentioned in the tagline.

I have 2 tables, `User` and `Userlanguages`.

A single user can have multiple languages associated. I want these multiple languages in a single row separated by a semi-colon (;)

My `Userlanguages` table looks like this:

| User | Language |
| --- | --- |
| ANDY | English |
| ANDY | Korean |
| ANDY | Spanish |
| TOM | English |
| TOM | Spanish |

Expected output :

| User | Language |
| --- | --- |
| ANDY | English; Korean; Spanish |
| TOM | English; Spanish |

Please suggest a proper SQL query to achieve this output.

SQL query used :

```
SELECT  
    [User].[userID]
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [UserLanguages].[languagesID]
           FROM UserLanguages
           WHERE [User].[userID] = [UserLanguages].[userID_student]
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM 
    User;
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Comment: SQL Server has [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function

Comment: You're missing a comma after `User.userID`. You also need a `GROUP BY userID` and the subquery should finish `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')`

Comment: I am receiving the below error after doing the suggested changes.

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

Comment: use Cast([UserLanguages].[languagesID] as varchar) instead of [UserLanguages].[languagesID]

Comment: Your version of SSMS is irrelevant - SSMS is only the client GUI, V15.0 is not even in the current list of supported versions. What version of SQL Server are you using? Ie the latest 2019 or a prior version 2017/2016/2014 etc?